# JavaScript dropdown menu - parts disappearing on a Mac?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My website has various pages and every page has a duplicated navigation menu along the top. This works fine on every browser on a PC. However, when on a Mac in safari or iPad, it works only on some pages.

When on portraits page, the text from the drop down menu 'Info' disappears, as does the text from the client area drop down menu.

These menu's work fine on all other pages, and the code is exactly the same, I copy and pasted it so I really don't understand why this can happen. The links still work, if you click in the blank space it takes you to the link, but you can't actually see what you clicking.

I've updated all my JavaScript files and can't think of anything else to try.

[www.yorkshirephotographer.net](http://www.yorkshirephotographer.net/)

**Code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    /* for top navigation */
    jQuery(" #menu ul ").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix
    jQuery(" #menu li").hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideDown(400);
    },function(){
        jQuery(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
    });
    jQuery(" #menu2 ul ").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix
    jQuery(" #menu2 li").hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideDown(400);
    },function(){
        jQuery(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you really have java ? Or javascript ? BTW, if you want us to fix something, we have to see code, or at least something concrete (and don't simply send us to a site asking us to debug it : reduce the problem to a simple case).

Comment: O, good question, I'm not sure.

Comment: So you're not using java. As is frequently said here, "java is to javascript as car is to carpet". Those are very different languages and you can't code in java and not know it.

Comment: This is really doing my head in, Im trying to send you the coding for the page, along with the CSS but it wont post....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it might be a rendering problem.
Try adding some fix css to your elements :

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

It should force rendering...
you can do it with javascript like this:

```
jQuery("#menu ul, #menu li").css("-webkit-transform", "translateZ(0)");
```

You can also apply the css property to all children of `#menu`. I'd add the anchor selector too:

```
jQuery("#menu, #menu ul, #menu li, #menu a").css("-webkit-transform", "translateZ(0)");
```

If it still doesn't work, try removing cufons.

Comment: after your comment /* for top navigation */

Comment: jQuery should be enough but if you wanted your website to work for non javascript clients (which I doubt) the css method would be the one to go with.

Comment: wahoo, I love you. It now works on my ipad safari....however, in an effort to check other browsers on a mac system i downloaded chrome for the ipad, is there another bit of code i need as it isnt working in there. Whats the CSS method?

Comment: I'll tell you if you +1 my answer ;-) just kidding it should work for both... The jQuery method adds a css property to your objects so both methods are equivalent in effect.

Comment: is there a reason it wont work on Ipad chrome? I tried +1 you but it wont let me, think im too new :(

Comment: Great, not sure what u mean by children or anchor selector....I could remove cufon, I had to update that for it to work IE9. Id rather not though. Am i right in saying cufon styles by text....or if im wrong what does cufon do, ive been wondering for a few weeks.....