# Disable jquery line in .js file when on mobile device, OR only use when Mac/IPAD?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    /* for top navigation */

    jQuery("#menu ul, #menu li").css("-webkit-transform", "translateZ(0)");
    jQuery(" #menu ul ").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix
    jQuery(" #menu li").hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideDown(400);
    },function(){
        jQuery(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
    });

    jQuery(" #menu2 ul ").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix
    jQuery(" #menu2 li").hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideDown(400);
    },function(){
        jQuery(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
    });
});
```

This code is from dropdown.js and is for my nav menu on www.yorkshirephotographer.net 
I had to add the top line of code - webkit transform due to the menu not functioning correctly on Mac's and IPAD's. 
See more about this and why I added this code line here -

[JavaScript dropdown menu - parts disappearing on a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384219/javascript-dropdown-menu-parts-disappearing-on-a-mac)

But now the menu doesn't work on Mobile devices. When you tap to click, a box appears for a second but under the main menu text, like your pressing under the link, which results in the link not activating - so basically the menu bar doesnt work on mobiles.

I've checked without that line of code and it works again, but it wont work on a Mac....so Need to disable it on mobile devices or only read when its Mac/Apple OS.....

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    // If Mac, or iPad, apply the following...
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(Mac|iPad)/i)) {

        jQuery("#menu ul, #menu li").css("-webkit-transform", "translateZ(0)");
        jQuery(" #menu ul ").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix        
        jQuery(" #menu li").hover(function(){
            jQuery(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideDown(400);
        },function(){
            jQuery(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
        });

        jQuery(" #menu2 ul ").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix
        jQuery(" #menu2 li").hover(function(){
            jQuery(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideDown(400);
        },function(){
            jQuery(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
        });

    } // End of Mac, iPad additional fixes ----

});
```

**PS:** If you want to include your additional fixes for the the iPhone, and iPod, you may replace `if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(Mac|iPad)/i))` with `if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(Mac|iPhone|iPod|iPad)/i))`

Hope this helps, let me know about your results mate.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the OS from the [navigator](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/navigator.shtml) object's platform property.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        // Mac OS detection
        if (/Mac[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.platform)) {
            /* for top navigation */
            jQuery("#menu ul, #menu li").css("-webkit-transform", "translateZ(0)");
            jQuery(" #menu li").hover( function() {
                    jQuery(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideDown(400); }, 
                function() { 
                    jQuery(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"}); 
                });

            jQuery(" #menu2 li").hover( function() {
                    jQuery(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideDown(400); }, 
                function() {
                    jQuery(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
                });
            // Opera Fix
            if (/Opera[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){ 
                jQuery(" #menu ul ").css({display: "none"}); 
                jQuery(" #menu2 ul ").css({display: "none"});
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Or you can use the great javascript [session.js](https://github.com/codejoust/session.js) library ;)

Which returns you browser os value and also if the device is tablet, phone or mobile.

**EDIT :** add code ready to use and remove w3c references

Comment: My understanding is basic really - What code should I use and where should I place it? Thank you. Once its obtained what browser or OS - how do I get it to 'Ignore' and/or 'Use' the line of code in question?

Comment: @user1665117 just edit my post with full code, enjoy and give feed back if necessary

Comment: @HillBilly.Developer you're right, moment of weakness, my fault :s